# Unwrap with guard statement from json to AnyObject

Tags: json, xcode, swift, guard

I need to parse data from dictionaries (containing the same keys) in a json file. The problem is that in some dictionaries the value for the same key is a string, but it is a float in the other. (Optional read: the reason for this is that the csv to json converter I use does recognise a negative decimal number as a string because there's a blank space after the dash: "- 4.50". I will delete that space and cast to float once the string is unwrapped.)

I tried to do the following:

```
guard let profit = data["profit"] as? AnyObject else { return }
if profit as! Float != nil {
  // Use this value
} else {
  // It is a string, so delete the space and cast to float
}
```

There must be an easy fix for this but no matter how I put the ? and ! in the guard statement, the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type of a dictionary value is `AnyObject` anyway, so this type casting is redundant.

You can check the type simply with the `is` operand

```
guard let profit = data["profit"] else { return }
if profit is Float {
  // Use this value
} else {
  // It is a string, so delete the space and cast to float
}
```

Or including proper type casting

```
guard let profit = data["profit"] else { return }
if let profitFloat = profit as? Float {
  // Use this value
} else if let profitString = profit as? String {
  // It is a string, so delete the space and cast to float
}
```